# Firebase auth in Flutter does not show captcha and stops the application

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, bloc

I connected authentication in flutter. When you click on the registration button when entering a phone number, the data is sent to the block, the browser opens, a second attempt is made to display the captcha, the browser disappears and the application stops.

Here's the code:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_multi_formatter/formatters/phone_input_formatter.dart';
import 'package:hmelnaya_lavka_app/bloc/register_bloc.dart';
import 'package:hmelnaya_lavka_app/utils/style.dart';
import 'package:nb_utils/nb_utils.dart';

class RegisterPhoneScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterPhoneScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<RegisterPhoneScreen> createState() => _RegisterPhoneScreenState();
}

class _RegisterPhoneScreenState extends State<RegisterPhoneScreen> {
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController(text: "+7");
  final TextEditingController otpController = TextEditingController();
  bool otpVisibility = false;
  String verificationID = "";
  int token = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final registerBloc = BlocProvider.of<RegisterBloc>(context);

    return Container(
      child: BlocBuilder<RegisterBloc, RegisterState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          
          if (state is RegisterInitialState) {
            return Container(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text("Apply code"),
                  TextField(
                    controller: otpController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        registerBloc.add(VerifySentOtpEvent(
                            phone: verificationID, token: otpController.text));
                      },
                      child: Text("Press to next"))
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else if (state is InitialState) {
            return Container(
              child: Column(children: [
                24.height,
                boldText(24, "Phone number"),
                TextField(
                  controller: _controller,
                  inputFormatters: [PhoneInputFormatter()],
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      verificationID = _controller.text;
                      registerBloc.add(
                          MainScreenRegisterEvent(phone: _controller.text));
                    },
                    child: Text("Press to registration"))
              ]),
            );
          } else {
            return Container(
              child: Text("Omg..."),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and bloc:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


part 'register_event.dart';
part 'register_state.dart';

class RegisterBloc extends Bloc<RegisterEvent, RegisterState> {
  RegisterBloc() : super(InitialState()) {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    on<MainScreenRegisterEvent>((event, emit) async {
      final Completer<void> completer = Completer();
      final _phone = event.phone;
      print("Start Bloc");
      await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
          phoneNumber: _phone,
          verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
            await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
            print("VERIFICATION COMLITED!");
          },
          verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException error) {
            if (error.code == "invalid-phone-number") {
              print("ERROR NUMBER BLOC");
            }
          },
          codeSent: (verificationId, forceResendingToken) async {
            emit(RegisterInitialState(
                id: verificationId, token: forceResendingToken ?? 0));
          },
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) {
            //Обратнвый вызов по истечении времени автоматического получения кода.
            
          });
    });
    on<VerifySentOtpEvent>((event, emit) async {
      print("Verify");
      FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
      PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
          verificationId: event.phone, smsCode: event.token);
      try {
        await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        emit(InitialNewUserState(
            textToUser: "Your are register", newScreen: true));
      } catch (e) {
        emit(InitialNewUserState(
            textToUser: "Error", newScreen: true));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

In the absence of bloc, everything just works in one screen (by adding functions), but I want to separate screens and logic. I think the bug is in Emit, which is called directly in codesend, but the documentation says otherwise.

Error:

```
E/flutter ( 4075):   **BAD**
E/flutter ( 4075):   on<Event>((event, emit) {
E/flutter ( 4075):     future.whenComplete(() => emit(...));
E/flutter ( 4075):   });
E/flutter ( 4075): 
E/flutter ( 4075):   **GOOD**
E/flutter ( 4075):   on<Event>((event, emit) async {
E/flutter ( 4075):     await future.whenComplete(() => emit(...));
E/flutter ( 4075):   });
E/flutter ( 4075): 
E/flutter ( 4075): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
E/flutter ( 4075): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
E/flutter ( 4075): #2      _Emitter.call (package:bloc/src/emitter.dart:114:7)
E/flutter ( 4075): #3      new RegisterBloc.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:hmelnaya_lavka_app/bloc/register_bloc.dart:35:15)
E/flutter ( 4075): #4      MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber.<anonymous closure> (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:625:19)
E/flutter ( 4075): #5      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1594:10)
E/flutter ( 4075): #6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
E/flutter ( 4075): #7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
E/flutter ( 4075): #8      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:123:11)
E/flutter ( 4075): #9      _HandleErrorStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:253:10)
E/flutter ( 4075): #10     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
E/flutter ( 4075): #11     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1594:10)
E/flutter ( 4075): #12     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
E/flutter ( 4075): #13     _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:515:14)
E/flutter ( 4075): #14     _PendingEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:620:11)
E/flutter ( 4075): #15     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:7)
E/flutter ( 4075): #16     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter ( 4075): #17     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
E/flutter ( 4075):
```